# Accessing Previous Purchases

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

I purchased Steel Storm Burning Retribution back in 2011. Now that I have a new laptop with  13.04 I logged in to the software Center to re-install it, but the Previous Purchases screen comes up empty.

I can search for it, but clicking on **More Info** results in a message that it's not available in my current software sources. If I don't log in, I can see it and have the option to buy it. Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Does this relate to your problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/361672/software-purchases-accounts-issue?rq=1

Comment: Do they show up on software-sources listing? on your old system?

Answer (score 1):

The Software Center has some info that should help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSoftwareCenter#reinstalling-purchases