# Software purchases & accounts issue

Tags: software-center

I have installed 13.10 on a new computer and want to tranfer my purchase (Braid) there.

I have read [this page](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-reinstall-software-ive-purchased-in-the-past/) about how to do this.

However, when I log in to https://software-center.ubuntu.com/subscriptions, nothing appears. My guess is that when I purchased this game, I used an older email address than the one I am currently using.

Ideally I would like to be able to transfer this purchase to my current ubuntu one account. Or, if this is not possible, at least to have a chance to know with which account this purchase has been done so I can have a try to reinstall it somewhere else.

NB: In the Ubuntu Software Center on my older computer the game is still there and marked as "already purchased".

EDIT:

This is not an upgrade issue, as my old computer has not been upgraded to 13.10, and my newer computer is, well, new, 13.10 being its first OS. Note that I don't see my purchases on the software center web site on my old as well as my new computer, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check your software sources, the Other Software tab....I noticed the upgrade unchecked the entries there for my purchases.  Check there and re-check the boxes.  Maybe that will do it.

Comment: No, this is not due to an upgrade problem -- actually my old laptop has not been upgraded to 13.10 yet. I am editing my question to add  this extra information.